# DB2 Select from not empty columns with column name

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with the following data in the DB2:

```
Location|Phone|Email  |Changedatetime
null    |3314 |null   |12/07/2019 10:00
null    |null |e@e.com|12/07/2019 11:00
```

It is a list of changes in the related table.
I need a select based on this table with not null column name and value

I need to select it the following way if possible:

```
Attribute|Value  |Changedatetime
Phone    |3314   |12/07/2019 10:00
Email    |e@e.com|12/07/2019 11:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use `union`

```
select 'Phone' as attribute, Phone as value, Changedatetime
from tablename where phone is not null
union 
select 'Email', email, Changedatetime
from tablename where email is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case statement.

```
select 
case when Phone is not null then 'Phone' else 'Email' end as Attribute , 
case when Phone is not null then Phone  else Email end as Value ,
Changedatetime
from tablename
```